# How to use mod_rewrite to redirect requests of username but rest to a frontend index?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect requests of username to a script but the all rest to a specific index called frontend.php using a .htaccess and a mod_rewrite.

Unfortunately, this failed and I keep struggling:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/user/([^/]+)$ profile/profile.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ profile/profile.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ frontend.php [L]
```

- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: it worked! swaping and getting rid of the slash! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to swap the last 2 lines against each other?